# How Make A Variable As A Placeholder In A HTML Template In Flask?

Tags: python, flask

So, I was making an HTML template in Flask And Wanted To Put The Form Label As The PlaceHolder Of A TextBox, But when I try to do so, Flask gives an error.

My Code:

```
<div class="input">
    {{ form.username(class="txtb", placeholder={{ form.username.label }}) }}
```

The Error Flask Gives:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'
```

And when I try to print the label normally like

```
<h4>{{ form.username.label }}</h4>
```

It works completely fine.

Also, this also works perfectly.

```
<div class="input">
    {{ form.username(class="txtb", placeholder="Username") }}
```

I Don't Know Where I Went Wrong.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Why not just `placeholder=form.username.label`?

Comment: Thanks for helping but I tried what you said, but the placeholder said "<label for="username">Username</label>". Got any more ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use label's text because as you noticed label itself is full `<label>` element.

`{{ form.username(class="txtb", placeholder=form.username.label.text) }}`